# Do we actually need sessions in node.js or we can store users data in global variable based on user's ip?

Tags: node.js, session, authorization

I was always using sessions in PHP and now switched no NODE.JS server which is running constantly (unlike PHP). So I'm not sure if I really need sessions in node.js to store user's data.
I can make a simple IP-based global user's storage variable and store any user's data here. Here is an example:

```
import Express from "express";
import sessions from "express-session";

class HttpServer {

    app; users = [];

    constructor() {
        this.init ();
    }

    init () {

        this.app = new Express();

        /*
        this.#app.use(sessions({
                secret: 'Secret word',
                resave: false,
                saveUninitialized: true,
                cookie: { secure: false , maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000}
            }
        ))

         */

        this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
            this.checkUser (req, res);
            next();
        })

        this.app.listen(8080);

    }


    checkUser (req, res, next) {
        let user = this.getUserByIp (req.ip);
        if (! user) { // Add new user
            this.users.push ({ip: req.ip, isLogged: false});
        }

    }

    getUserByIp (ip) {
        for (let i=0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
            if (this.users[i].ip === ip) {
                return this.users[i];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    authorizeUser (ip) {
        let user = this.getUserByIp (ip);
        if (user) {
            user.isLogged = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Assuming everyone with the same IP is the same user doesn't really work. People on the same wifi connection will have the same IP. People using the same VPN endpoint will have the same IP. People (using Safari on iOS) with iCloud Private Relay enabled with not have unique IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session is just a piece of memory (or database record) indexed by a cookie ID.  You are proposing a piece of memory indexed by an IP address.

The problem with an IP address is that many people may be proxied through the same IP address (multiple home users, multiple WiFi users at a Starbucks or corporate users who connect via a corporate proxy) which can then mix up credentials between users which is disastrous.

Do NOT rely on every user having a unique IP address.  It just isn't so.  My son, wife and myself when connecting from home all appear to come from the same IP address.

Multiple people using WiFi at a Starbucks may all appear to be coming from the same IP address.

A mobile user may have a changing IP address as they move around in the mobile network (thus losing their session info every time the IP address changes) and then someone else reuses your old IP address.

People using VPNs will have who-knows-what IP address that will not necessarily remain the same for that computer and those IP addresses will be shared with many other users also using the same VPN service and connecting to the same VPN servers.

---

There are very good reasons that sessions are based off an encrypted ID in a cookie.